# PyCharm - Database connection. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to setup conection to my local db (mysql) via PyCharm. I am working on macbook pro.

I am using this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3C0iO1yqhk).

But, when i trying to test connections, i am getting this error:

```
    Connection to Data Source failed
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1709)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.connect(Unknown Source)
    in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:158)
```

But i have no problem connect to mysql via terminal

```
mysql -u root --password=123
```

**UPD**

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -D lp
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 lp
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysql -u root -p -h localhost lp
connected
```

**UPD**

```
mysql> select host, user, password != '' from mysql.user;
+-----------+------+----------------+
| host      | user | password != '' |
+-----------+------+----------------+
| localhost | root |              1 |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |              1 |
| ::1       | root |              1 |
+-----------+------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user(), current_user();
+----------------+----------------+
| user()         | current_user() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is screenshot of my settings:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your MySQL configuration may forbid TCP connections (only via sockets .. or whatever it is called there in Linux world)

Comment: Please check from command line if you can connect using `mysql -u root --password=123 lp`

Comment: @LazyOne if that was the case I understand he should be getting a "Can't connect" error, not "Access denied".

Comment: Can you try to connect to the schema with the -D probably you don't have permission to go in the schema

Comment: @rsanchez Could be (as I do not remember exact wording). In such case OP needs to check access settings (privileges) -- maybe he somehow explicitly restricted access for `root` user for that table. For me it's definitely a security settings issue on DB side.

Comment: @rsanchez mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -D lp - denied, mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 lp - denied, mysql -u root -p -h localhost lp - works fine. What is my next step?

Comment: Your case is really weird. Please add the results of `select host, user, password != '' from mysql.user;` and `select user(), current_user();`

Comment: @rsanchez added output to question

Comment: Another shot, what's the result of `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name in ('port', 'socket');`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some or both of these should fix your problem:

Check the results of `select host, user, password, Select_priv from mysql.user;`.

If the `password` field is not the same for all rows then do:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('123');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('123');
```

If `Select_priv` is not 'Y' for all rows then do:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'::1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**EDIT**

As neither of these was true, the only option left was that there was more than one instance of MySQL running on the machine, and one was receiving the connections made via socket and the other one was receiving the connections made via TCP.

Comment: So strange... 
password is the same in each field and Select_priv is 'Y'. But I did this commands anyway. Still in same position =(. Btw, mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 lp - Denied, but mysql -u root -p -h localhost lp
- OK.

Comment: @DenisKabalkin the only thing I can think of then is that you have two MySQL instances running, and are accessing one when using sockets and the other when using TCP

Comment: oh my. i found very old mysqld zombie process bind to 127.0.0.1. killed it and everything works fine. Thanks for help.

Comment: @DenisKabalkin that's great, I edited the answer so the right solution is mentioned in its body

Answer (score 4):

maybe you dont have permission to the schema ? 
try this:

```
 mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -D lp
```

**Update**
You have access to the database but you dont have access to the schema.

```
 GRANT ALL ON `lp`.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: i wanted to add it as comment but i had no reputation :(

Comment: Updated my question. Yes, i cannot connect like this. What i should do next?

Comment: you have accesss to the db but you dont have access to the schema. you neet to use grant. check this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/335740/oracle-grant-all-privileges-to-schema)

Comment: Tried this, but steel have same problem.
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -D lp
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: you did grant all on lp ? root is supposed to have access to everything anyway. you may aswell do GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; (it will give access to all schemas/tables to root). edit: sry starts wont show because of markdown. it sounds like your users are messed up somehow. grant all star.star should work

Comment: try GRANT ALL ON star.star TO 'root'@'localhost' identified by "123" WITH GRANT OPTION; replace start with * if it doesn't work update the question with your mysql.user

Comment: @FooBarUser, same thing

Comment: hm i am not expert on sql priviliges but i think your user table looks ok. i once had similar problem with permissions even if i granted permissions it didnt work. i re-installed mysql because i allready had a backup and it was less time consuming. if you know how to proper fix it is better. i personaly had something messed up on my users similar to what rsanchez recommended. at least you are closer to the problem now.